# (Oracle)Removing outlier

Tags: sql, outliers

The goal is to get the average after removing +- standard deviation  exceeding outliers.
For EQUIP E1, MODEL M1 in my table ACTUAL_OUTPUT, there are 6 data, 10, 10, 100000, 10,10.10.
Therefore the expected result is 10 because, in this case, the 100000 is a outlier.

My table and data are as below.
And I have made query for this.
Could there be better way then this?

```
 --Table and data  

 CREATE TABLE ACTUAL_OUTPUT
     (
       EQUIP VARCHAR2(15),
       MODEL VARCHAR2(15),
       LOT VARCHAR2(15),
       VAL NUMBER
    )
    delete FROM ACTUAL_OUTPUT;
    INSERT INTO ACTUAL_OUTPUT VALUES('E1','M1','L1',10);
    INSERT INTO ACTUAL_OUTPUT VALUES('E1','M1','L2',10);
    INSERT INTO ACTUAL_OUTPUT VALUES('E1','M1','L3',100000);
    INSERT INTO ACTUAL_OUTPUT VALUES('E1','M1','L4',10);
    INSERT INTO ACTUAL_OUTPUT VALUES('E1','M1','L5',10);
    INSERT INTO ACTUAL_OUTPUT VALUES('E1','M1','L6',10);
    INSERT INTO ACTUAL_OUTPUT VALUES('E1','M2','L7',50);



 -- Is there a better way then this?     
   SELECT avg(VAL_2) OUTLIER_REMOVED
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    EQUIP,
    MODEL,
    CASE WHEN
    VAL <= AVG(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP,MODEL)+2*STDDEV(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP,MODEL)
    AND 
    VAL >= AVG(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP,MODEL)-2*STDDEV(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP,MODEL)
    THEN VAL ELSE NULL END VAL_2
    FROM ACTUAL_OUTPUT
    )
    WHERE EQUIP='E1' AND MODEL = 'M1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT avg(VAL_2) as OUTLIER_REMOVED
FROM (SELECT ao.*,
             STDDEV(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP, MODEL) as val_stddev,
             AVG(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP, MODEL) as val_avg
      FROM ACTUAL_OUTPUT ao
      WHERE EQUIP = 'E1' AND MODEL = 'M1'
     ) ao
WHERE VAL >= val_avg - 2 * val_stddev AND
      VAL <= val_avg + 2 * val_stddev;
```

However, the performance should be the same, assuming your database has a good optimizer.

What are the differences?

- The `where` clause is in the subquery.  Most optimizers should do this anyway, but I like to have the filtering as soon as possible, just in case the optimizer gets confused.
- The calculation for the average and standard deviation is expressed only once.  Once again, a good optimizer would not run the window functions multiple times.
- The formula for filtering is in the outer query.  Because it doesn't use window functions, it is much simpler to read and validate.
- This does not depend on `NULL` being ignored in the outer query.  The outlier values are removed by filtering.